# how to change a column to continuous data to plot it on ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Hello I am having trouble with drawing a plot of the decrease in metabolites over time for three different animal.

This is the code I used for the plot:

```
all_met %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Inosine mp),names_to="Metabolites",values_to="concentration") %>%
  group_by(Animal,Day, Metabolites) %>%   
  summarise(mean = mean(concentration), sd = sd(concentration)) %>%   
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Day),y= mean, group = Animal, colour = Animal)) +   
  geom_point()+   
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se = FALSE, formula =  y~x)+   
  stat_regline_equation()
```

Which gives me:

[image]

You can see the x axis is evenly distributed but I don't want that... From what I googled it is assuming my data is in discrete but I can't use
`scale_x_continuous` so I am wondering how do I fix it.

I also want to add the R^2 value as well but it overlapped the equation thus also is there a way to move the equation to other place of the plot?

**DATA**

```
structure(list(Animal = c("Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", 
"Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", 
"Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", 
"Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", 
"Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Beef", "Lamb", 
"Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", 
"Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", 
"Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", 
"Lamb", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", 
"Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", 
"Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison",
"Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", 
"Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", 
"Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison", "Venison",
"Venison", "Venison"), Day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.125, 
0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
1.75, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `all_met %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(`Inosine mp`),names_to="Metabolites",values_to="concentration") %>%
  group_by(Animal,Day, Metabolites) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(concentration), sd = sd(concentration)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Day),y= mean, group = Animal, colour = Animal)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se = FALSE, formula =  y~x)+
  stat_regline_equation()`

Comment: Hi Mayolee. Could you update your data or code? As it is your code is not runnable as your data contains only columns Animal and Day.

Comment: One more point: `ggplot2` is not assuming your data is discrete. You made it discrete using `factor`. Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve by that and why "you can't use scale_x_continuous"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you declared x as a factor (`x=factor(Day)`) your x axis is discrete and not continuous (i.e. numeric). Remove the factor function and you will get a continuous axis.